# GreenDAO QueryBuilder dynamically add conditions

Tags: android, sqlite, greendao

I currently have a list of userIds and I am trying to create a query to get all of those from my DB.

this is what I have in mind, I'm just not that sure that it's possible:

```
ArrayList<Users> listOfUsers = getCurrentUsers(); 
// lets assume that by now I have a list of users
QueryBuilder<Users> qb = getUsersDao().queryBuilder();
for(Users usr : listOfUsers) {
    qb.where(Properties.userId.eq(usr.getUserId());
}
List result = qb.list();
```

I haven't seen any documentation about what is the right way of doing this and I want to know if this is the correct way of creating a dynamic query in GreenDAO.

***EDIT:***

I tried this and the result was a `NullPointerException` in the line of the declaration on the `QueryBuilder`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try using the `IN` query instead, it will run faster + you can cache your Query object.
so lets say you have

```
List<String> userIds;
```

you can get the list with:

```
qb.where(Properties.UserId.in(userIds))
```

if this is an operation that you do frequently, it is better to cache the Query. to do that, prepare the query as follows for only once:

```
Query<User> query = qb.where(Properties.UserId.in("?")).build();
```

then when you need to run it :

```
query.setParameter(0, userIds);
return query.list();
```

Comment: Setting a List or Array to an already prepared Query with setParameter(0, userIds) does not work in my case. In GreenDao source they will just call userIds.toString() to apply the parameter.